# Can't shared an array of structs in shared memory

Tags: c, struct, shared-memory

i created a library that initialize and fill an array of strutc shared 2 process. The problem is that it doesn't work, instead i created an array of int and it work correctly. Bu i need this array in shared memory, what dis i miss?

EDIT: I have a theory but I need confirmation cause i'm studing now c and sh memory....is possible taht the problem are the transaction declared by pointer in the struct of block, and for that reason in the sh memory doesn't result anything?And this error force the process to close for certain reason?

EDIT: so i forgot to post the print function. I forced the size to be 0 cause i want to inset only 1 element and at least print only one. But the print function stuck after the first print before the if and i don't know why. I think that is cause the shared doen't work but for print  "Blocco n°0" it suggest that `Masterbook[i].id` have some value inside.

EDIT : changed the `char*` but doesn't work too.

struct:

```
struct Transaction {
    char timestamp[24];
    int sender; /* pid user sent */
    int receiver;
    int reward;
    int money;
};

struct Block
{
    int id;
    struct Transaction* tr1;
    struct Transaction* tr2;
    struct Transaction* reward;
};
```

masterbook.c

```
    struct Block* MasterBook;
    int sizeMaster = -1;
        void initMasterBook(){
            int shmid,sizeid;
            shmid = shmget(SH_KEY_MASTERBOOK,MAX_MASTER*sizeof(struct Block),IPC_CREAT | 0666);
            if(shmid == -1) {
                perror("shmget error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            MasterBook = (struct Block*)shmat(shmid,NULL,0);
            if ( MasterBook == -1 ) {
                perror ( "Error in shmat: " );
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
               
        }
        
        void freeMasterBook(){
            shmdt((void *) MasterBook); 
        }
        int addBlock(struct Block block){
            if(sizeMaster >= MAX_MASTER-1) return -1;
            ++sizeMaster;
            block.id = sizeMaster;
            MasterBook[sizeMaster] = block;
            return 0;
        }
int printMasterBook(){
    if(sizeMaster < 0) {
        printf("\nMasterbook vuoto");
        return -1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for ( i; i <= sizeMaster; i++)
    {
        printf("\nBlocco n° : %d",MasterBook[i].id);
        
        if(MasterBook[i].tr1 != NULL){
            printf("\n\tTransazione n° 1 : ");
        struct Transaction *temp = MasterBook[i].tr1;
        printf("\n\t\tReceiver: %d",temp->receiver);
        printf("\n\t\tSender: %d",temp->sender);
        printf("\n\t\tReward: %d",temp->reward);
        printf("\n\t\tTimestamp: %s",temp->timestamp);
        }else printf("\nThere's no transaction 1 set!");

        if(MasterBook[i].tr2 != NULL){
            printf("\n\tTransazione n° 2 : ");
        struct Transaction *temp2 = MasterBook[i].tr2;
        printf("\n\t\tReceiver: %d",temp2->receiver);
        printf("\n\t\tSender: %d",temp2->sender);
        printf("\n\t\tReward: %d",temp2->reward);
        printf("\n\t\tTimestamp: %s",temp2->timestamp);
        }else printf("\nThere's no transaction 2 set!");

        if(MasterBook[i].reward != NULL){
            printf("\n\tTransazione Reward : ");
        struct Transaction *temp3 = MasterBook[i].reward;
        printf("\n\t\tReceiver: %d",temp3->receiver);
        printf("\n\t\tSender: %d",temp3->sender);
        printf("\n\t\tReward: %d",temp3->reward);
        printf("\n\t\tTimestamp: %s",temp3->timestamp);
        }else printf("\nThere's no transaction reward set!");
    
        printf("finish print");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

master.c:

```
initMasterBook();
printf("\nthe size id: %d",sizeMaster);
printMasterBook();
struct Block v;
struct Transaction t1;
t1.money = 4;
t1.receiver = 2;
t1.sender = 3;
strcpy(t1.timestamp,"ciao");
t1.reward = 4;
v.tr1 = &t1;
addBlock(v);
printMasterBook();
 printf("\nthe size id: %d",sizeMaster);
```

node.c

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    initMasterBook();
    sizeMaster=0;
    printMasterBook();
    freeMasterBook();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `timestamp` is a `char*` that you store in shared memory - but does it point at a string that is also stored in shared memory? No. `"ciao"` is not stored in shared memory.

Comment: so, if i want to shared am array of struct i have to share every component of the struct? or the problem is the char* ?

Comment: The problem is what the pointer points to. I.e. not the `char*` is the problem but the `*(t1.timestamp)`, the pseudo-string (the 0-terminated sequence of characters, which is the closest that C gets to having a decent string type). You need to answer yourself where that is, and whether that "where" is inside shared memory.

Comment: Need to mention, my "wise" comment above is all based on the comment by Ted Lyngmo. I did not spot that myself. Only try to get Teds idea across.

Comment: As requirement i have to insert in Transaction a string that store the time when it was sent to a node. So, it will be fill in the program when an user sent a transaction to a node. Now i wrote t1.timestamp = "ciao"; only to test the program. This is the problem why the array's not shared?

Comment: @MatteoPagliarello The `char*` is fine, but `"ciao"` is stored in the non-shared memory of one process. You'll have to store `"ciao"` in shared memory too. You could make it easy and make `timestamp` an array instead: `char timestamp[24 /* or whatever size is required */];` and then `strcpy()` `"ciao"` into that.

Comment: Ok,i'll try! :)

Comment: If you get it to work you can create your own answer here to help others. Credit Ted (i.e. not me...).

Comment: It's not the solution of problem, but thank i use this solution for timestamp

Comment: Even if the `char *` points to something in shared memory in one process, that shared memory segment is likely to be mapped to a different virtual address in another process, rendering the pointer invalid in that other process.

Comment: Ok, i understood that the char* is a problem, but i want only a string in the struct, nothing else. The point is that the print stuck and seem like the process crash without ecxeption or error.

Comment: If you want "a string in the struct" try Teds "array instead".

Comment: @IanAbbott You imply the need for de-/serialisation, am I right? This is more complex than I thought. My "wise" comment is only by sheer luck not fundamentally wrong. Or do you also think of the direct char array proposed by Ted?

Comment: i implemented the solution proposed by ted but nothing change

Comment: But that let me think about other problem that i wrote on the text as "EDIT"

Comment: Is it correctr the way a create the shared memory? is size correct?

Comment: @Yunnosch An alternative to in-line de-/serialisation is to replace pointers with offsets.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of output changing the pointer in the struct and rearrange the code.

```
struct Transaction {
    int empty;
    char timestamp[30];
    int sender; /* pid user sent */
    int receiver;
    int reward;
    int money;
};

struct Block
{
    int id;
    struct Transaction tr1;
    struct Transaction tr2;
    struct Transaction reward;
};
```

print that had problem:

```
int printMasterBook(){
    if(sizeMaster < 0) {
        printf("\nMasterbook vuoto");
        return -1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for ( i; i <= sizeMaster; i++)
    {
        printf("\nBlocco n° : %d",MasterBook[i].id);
        
        if(MasterBook[i].tr1.empty != -1){
            printf("\n\tTransazione n° 1 : ");
        printf("\n\t\tReceiver: %d",MasterBook[i].tr1.receiver);
        printf("\n\t\tSender: %d",MasterBook[i].tr1.sender);
        printf("\n\t\tReward: %d",MasterBook[i].tr1.reward);
        printf("\n\t\tTimestamp: %s",MasterBook[i].tr1.timestamp);
        }else printf("\nThere's no transaction 1 set!");

        if(MasterBook[i].tr2.empty!= -1){
            printf("\n\tTransazione n° 2 : ");
        printf("\n\t\tReceiver: %d",MasterBook[i].tr2.receiver);
        printf("\n\t\tSender: %d",MasterBook[i].tr2.sender);
        printf("\n\t\tReward: %d",MasterBook[i].tr2.reward);
        printf("\n\t\tTimestamp: %s",MasterBook[i].tr2.timestamp);
        }else printf("\nThere's no transaction 2 set!");

        if(MasterBook[i].reward.reward != -1){
            printf("\n\tTransazione Reward : ");
        printf("\n\t\tReceiver: %d",MasterBook[i].reward.receiver);
        printf("\n\t\tSender: %d",MasterBook[i].reward.sender);
        printf("\n\t\tReward: %d",MasterBook[i].reward.reward);
        printf("\n\t\tTimestamp: %s",MasterBook[i].reward.timestamp);
        }else printf("\nThere's no transaction reward set!");
    
        printf("finish print");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: link to follow and last question i hope: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73154651/calculate-dimension-of-shared-array-of-struct