# Calculate dimension of shared array of struct

Tags: arrays, c, shared-memory

i allocate a certain quantity of space in shared memory for my array. Now, if i want to set how many element are set in the array i tried to loop until one element is null but it doesn't work. There is a better solution to determinate the effective quantity of element setted in the array?

The first solution that i can figure is to set the size in a shared memory, but is it correct ? there is bettere solution?

struct :

```
struct Transaction {
    int empty;
    char timestamp[30];
    int sender; /* pid user sent */
    int receiver;
    int reward;
    int money;
};

struct Block
{
    int id;
    struct Transaction tr1;
    struct Transaction tr2;
    struct Transaction reward;
};

#define MAX_MASTER 100
```

masterbook.c

```
void initMasterBook(){
    int shmid;
    shmid = shmget(SH_KEY_MASTERBOOK,MAX_MASTER*sizeof(struct Block*),IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if(shmid == -1) {
        perror("shmget error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    MasterBook = (struct Block*)shmat(shmid,NULL,0);
    if ( MasterBook == -1 ) {
        perror ( "Error in shmat: " );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
       
}
void initSizeMaster(){
    struct Block* temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MASTER; i++)
    {
        temp = &MasterBook[i];
        if(temp == NULL) break;
        ++sizeMaster;
    }
    
    printf("Dimensione: %d",sizeMaster);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&MasterBook[i]` (and `temp`) will never be `NULL`. You either need to specify the amount of valid space explicitly, or terminate the array with a special sentinel element that can be distinguished from the valid elements (for example by using a special `id` member value such as -1).

```
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MASTER; i++)
    {
        if(MasterBook[i].id == -1) break;
        ++sizeMaster;
    }
```

Also, in `initMasterBook()`, the comparison `MasterBook == -1` is comparing a pointer with an integer, which is not correct (unless the integer is a zero constant).  It should be changed to `MasterBook == (void *)-1` as shown in the man page for `shmat`.

Comment: IS there  a way to set as default the value of a struct to -1 ? Or i can use id == 0 to say that a Block in the Masterbook is not initializated? Cause, now it print 00 element that have all the id equals to 0....is it cause they're not initializate?

Comment: The shared memory segment is created with its bytes initialized to 0. The process that fills in the array would be responsible for filling in the sentinel element at the end, but you can choose any sentinel value you want as long as it is distinguishable from a valid, non-sentinel value. If the array is to be filled to the maximum will all valid values, there is no need for a sentinel as long as all the processes agree on the maximum size.